# Pandas HD5-query, where expression fails

Tags: python-2.7, pandas

I want to query a HDF5-file. I do

```
df.to_hdf(pfad,'df', format='table')
```

to write the dataframe on disc.

To read I use

```
hdf = pandas.HDFStore(pfad)
```

I have a list that contains `numpy.datetime64` values called expirations and try to read the portion of the hd5 table into a dataframe, that has values between `expirations[1]` and `expirations[0]` in column `"expiration"`. Column expiration entries have the format `Timestamp('2002-05-18 00:00:00')`.

I use the following command:

```
df = hdf.select('df',
                where=['expiration<expiration[1]','expiration>=expirations[0]'])
```

However, this fails and produces a value error:

```
ValueError: The passed where expression: [expiration=expirations[0]]
            contains an invalid variable reference
            all of the variable refrences must be a reference to
            an axis (e.g. 'index' or 'columns'), or a data_column
            The currently defined references are: index,columns
```

Comment: you need to designate the query column as a data_column when you save the frame; see docs http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/io.html#query-via-data-columns

Comment: I used df.to_hdf(pfad,'df', format='table').

Comment: you need to specify data_columns as shown in the docs

Comment: When I write the hd5-file using the store object I arrive at this problem:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27174705/querying-a-hdf-store

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this code:

```
df = hdf.select('df', where='expiration < expirations[1] and expiration >= expirations[0]')
```

or, as a query:

```
df = hdf.query('expiration < @expirations[1] and expiration >= @expirations[0]')
```

Not sure which one fits best your case, I noticed you are trying to use 'where' to filter rows, without a string or a list, does it make sense ?