# Querying a HDF-store

Tags: pandas, hdf

I created a hd5 file by

```
hdf=pandas.HDFStore(pfad)
hdf.append('df', df, data_columns=True)
```

I have a list that contains numpy.datetime64 values called expirations and try to read the portion of the hd5 table into a dataframe, that has values between expirations[1] and expirations[0] in column "expiration". Column expiration entries have the format Timestamp('2002-05-18 00:00:00').

I use the following command:

```
df=hdf.select('df', where=('expiration<expiration[1] & expiration>=expirations[0]'))
```

However, I get ValueError: Unable to parse x
How should this be correctly done?

```
df.dtypes
Out[37]: 
adjusted stock close price           float64
expiration                    datetime64[ns]
strike                                 int64
call put                              object
ask                                  float64
bid                                  float64
volume                                 int64
open interest                          int64
unadjusted stock price               float64

df.info
Out[36]: 
<bound method DataFrame.info of             adjusted stock close price expiration  strike call put      ask  date                                                                          
2002-05-16                     5047.00 2002-05-18    4300        C  802.000
```

There is more columns but they aren't of interest for the query.

Comment: needs to be a string and not s tuple and you have a misspelled name

Comment: also helpful to show df.info() and your pandas version

Comment: indeed, that misspelling was also in my code snippet. Now it's the following error:
ValueError: cannot process expression [expiration<expirations[1] & expiration>=expirations[0]], [((expiration) < (2002-06-22T02:00:00.000000000+0200)) & ((expiration) >= (2002-05-18T02:00:00.000000000+0200))] is not a valid condition

Pandas version: 0.14.0
df.info: [3233578 rows x 9 columns]

Comment: pls update your question with ``df.info()`` (e.g. need to see the actual dtypes).

Comment: you have a disconnet here, what you are showing in the query is not the same as above. ``expiration`` appears to be a ``datetime64[ns]`` column, but you are showing a tz-aware datetime. Show a complete copy-pastable example from the beginning of what you are doing.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved!

I obtained expirations by

```
 df_expirations=df.drop_duplicates(subset='expiration')
 expirations=df['expiration'].values
```

This obviously changed the number format from datetime into tz datetime.
I reingeneered this by using

```
 expirations=df['expirations']
```

Now this query is working:
    del df
    df=hdf.select('df', where=('expiration=expirations[1]'))

Thanks for pointing me on the datetime format problem.