# Pandas read_hdf() returns "invalid variable reference" on valid where condition

Tags: python, pandas, hdfstore

I am trying to filter data from large HDF store to the required subset using the attribute *where* of method *read_hdb*:

```
phase = pd.read_hdf(DSPATH + '/phase-table.h5', 'phase', where='EXTSIDNAME=="A"')
```

According to the documentation I can specify any column defined in the dataset with basic logical conditions. According to Pandas  [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/io.html#querying) syntax *column_name == 'string literal'* is supported.

The library throws however a ValueError exception for any column I am trying to specify:

```
ValueError: The passed where expression: EXTSIDNAME=="A"
            contains an invalid variable reference
            all of the variable references must be a reference to
            an axis (e.g. 'index' or 'columns'), or a data_column
            The currently defined references are: index,columns
```

The only condition, which does not through the error is *'index=1'*.

The column exists in the data store. If I load it without filter I can see that I am trying to specify in the where condition do exist:

```
Index(['EXTSIDNAME', 'HOSTNAME', 'TIMESTP', 'SUM_ENDDATE','MODULE_ID','MODULENAME',
'MODULE_STARTDATE', 'MODULE_ENDDATE', 'PHASE_ID','PHASENAME', 
'PHASE_STARTDATE', 'PHASE_ENDDATE', 'ID', 'PhaseDuration'], dtype='object')
```

I am using the latest stable libraries from Anaconda bundle.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you created the HDF store with `to_hdf()`, you need to specify the `data_columns` parameter. A similar question is posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27170211/pandas-hd5-query-where-expression-fails).

An example:

```
d = {'Col': ['A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'D'],
     'X': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]}
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(d)
```

`df` looks like this:

```
  Col  X
0   A  1
1   A  2
2   A  3
3   B  4
4   B  5
5   B  6
6   C  7
7   D  8
```

Let's write it to .h5 file with `to_hdf()`. It's important that format equals `'table'`:

```
df.to_hdf('myhdf.h5', 'somekey', format='table')
```

Now let's read it with `read_hdf()`:

```
pd.read_hdf('myhdf.h5', key='somekey', where='Col==A')
```

Returns error:

```
ValueError: The passed where expression: Col==A
            contains an invalid variable reference
            all of the variable refrences must be a reference to
            an axis (e.g. 'index' or 'columns'), or a data_column
            The currently defined references are: index,columns
```

What gives?

When you do `to_hdf()`, you need to also define `data_columns` like this:

```
df.to_hdf('myhdf.h5', 'somekey', format='table', data_columns=['Col', 'X'])
```

Now you can read data from .h5 file using `where`:

```
pd.read_hdf('myhdf.h5', key='somekey', where='Col==A')
  Col  X
0   A  1
1   A  2
2   A  3
```

With `where` as a list:

```
pd.read_hdf('myhdf.h5', key='somekey', where=['Col==A', 'X==2'])
  Col  X
1   A  2
```

Comment: Exactly that! Moreover, it is stated in the Pandas [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/io.html), as I see it now, that _select will raise a ValueError if the query expression has an unknown variable reference. Usually this means that you are trying to select on a column that is not a data_column._  Additionally, instead of `data_columns=[ ...]` one can specify `data_columns=True` to index all columns and make them therefore available to filtering in `where` clause.

Comment: Cool! I didn't know about the `data_columns=True` part. I hope I remember that.